# Parsing a complicated object as a HttpContent parameter in the HTTPclient Post request

Tags: c#, json, api, post

I want to input an object as parameter inside the httpClient POST request.

However, since the object is quite complicated (layer inside layer), I am not sure how to put it as a parameter in the POST request.

I have set up the dto and it is something like this (I set this up according to the API call I will be using):

```
class Toolbox 
{
 public string ID { get; set; }
 public string[] Dates { get; set; }
 public Context Context { get; set; }
}
```

The Context class is something like this:

```
class Context
{
 public string Address { get; set; }
 public bool Data { get; set; }
}
```

The parameters that the API call needs is something like below:

```
{
 "ID": "ABC",
 "Dates": [
 "2022-08-05T00:00:00.000Z",
 "2025-05-29T00:00:00.000Z"
 ],
 "Context": {
 "Address": "2022-08-05T00:00:00",
 "Data": true
 }
}
```

In the httpClient call's body, I'm now doing something like this, but I believe I'm doing it in a wrong way.
**HTTP Post request's main body below**

```
public static double Calculation(string ID, string startDate, string endDate)
{
var context = new Context();
 {
 context.Address = "ABC";
 context.Data = true;
 }
var toolbox = new Toolbox
 {
 ID = index,
 Dates = {startDate, startDate},
 };
//What else should I do here? 
//Omitting httpClient set-up
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, **What should I put here?**).Result;
}
```

Since there should be no circular references in the object, after making sure of what object I should add as the 2nd parameter in PostAsync call, I also plan to do something like below to convert the custom object to HttpContent.

```
var content = new StringContent(complicatedObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

So once again, may I ask what should I do in HTTP Post request's main body to put the required parameters as an object?
Thank you very much for your kind assistance.

Comment: If you add `Newtonsoft.Json` package, you can do `using Newtonsoft.Json;` then `new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(complicatedObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: Similar to @zaitsman answer, I would use System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize() to serialize the data and add it the the content. System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer is the serializer that is used under the hood, its smaller and faster than the NewtonSoft version.